# how to update html page only when database changes

Tags: json, ajax

JS, which returns the first name:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'exm1.php',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        if( t<data.length){
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                $("#output").html(data[i].fn);
            }
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        // TODO: do error handling here
        console.log('An error has occurred while fetching lat/lon.');
    }
});
```

There are two things which I would like to sort out first:

1. It always overwrites the output div tag. I don't know how I can prevent this
2. `setInterval` should only run when there is a change in the database, or maybe when `data.length` changes, is there any way I could store the previous value of `data.length` and then compare with **new** `data.length`

Comment: Where's your HTML?

Comment: this code is  inside  an html
I want to update #output only when I change database

Answer (score 0):

If `#output` contains the first name, then you can target and save it into a variable on load

**Example:**

```
var firstname = $('#output').html();
```

And then all you have to do is compare the AJAX output with the variable.

**Example:**

```
if ( firstname != data )
    $('#output').html(firstname);
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent overwriting your div tag, use the following.

```js
$("#output").append(data[i].fn);
```

I don't understand what you mean by setinterval, please clarify in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the html inside of the div by using this (vanilla javascript)

```
var inTheOutPutDiv = document.getElementById("output");
inputTheOutPutDiv.html = inputTheOutPutDiv.html + data; // whatever
// or use  inputTheOutPutDiv.html+= data;
```

but sense you are using Jquery you can use append

```
$("#output").append(data);
```

You can instantiate a variable outside of your function that holds the length of your database query (scope).  Or you can return a database value that says if the info has been updated (a value of 1 if changed, a value of 0 if the same).  Then use a conditional statement to perform an action on the response.  You have many options.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't call setInterval only when the data changes, but you can run something at a set interval and *only update the #output html if the result is different*.

The reason #output is getting overwritten is because calling $.html("...") will *replace* the existing html with the argument. I'd recommend simply putting what you want to remain static on the page in a different div.

```
<div id='oldOutput'>
    Static Text Here: firstName?
    <span id='output'></span>
</div>
```

Now your ajax return will overwrite the  element and your static text will remain. However, you still have an issue in that every iteration of your loop will remove the string from before. If you want each loop to render cleanly, i'd recommend something along these lines:

```
success: function(data){
    if( t<data.length){            
        // if you want to flush the #output each time
        $("#output").html("");
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            $("#output").append(data[i].fn);
            // or you could put each entry in a div for later use
            // $("#output").append("<div id='div_"+ i +"'>" + data[i].fn + "</div>");
        }
    }
}
```

In this case (you're flushing the div each time) then if the data is the same you shouldn't notice it update. If you don't flush the div then the data will keep appending on to the end.

If this is what you want, but only when there is new data, then you can count the number of child divs in the #output span - if you wrap each item from the output in a div as I have above, you should be able to compare this to data.length:

```
success: function(data){
    if (t<data.length){
        // gets direction descendants of #output that are divs, 
        // and counts the length of the array returned
        var numItems = $("#output > div").length; 

        if(numItems != data.length){
            loop goes here..
        }
}
```

This will sort of work, it will only update when the number of items returned is different to the number of items you already have. However, if your script is returning a set of data and you need to filter it to see what's old and what's new, it's slightly different. You'll need to do include some sort of identifier (other than the data itself) to embed into the  to check if it exists later.

```
if ( $("[data-id=" + data[i].identifier +"]").length > 0 ) {
    // already exists, do nothing
} else {
    $("#output").append("<div data-id='"+ data[i].identifier +"' etc...
}
```

Comment: That sort of worked out  but also can I change a littke bit of this code to show some different output I mean sonething like firstname of 1st user lastname of 1st user and then after some space firstname of 2nd user and lastname of 2nd user

Comment: Yeah sure, you can customise your php to return anything you need, i'd recommend keeping your variables discrete, i.e. one var for first name, another for last name etc, so as not to manipulate strings later (have one fullName field and needing to remove the space between to get first and last name, etc). Then in your javascript ajax call, just include any relevant variablein the .append() function.